# Bar Chart PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces, jquery

Pessoal alguém sabe como deixar o gráfico de barras do primefaces desta maneira?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer aqui só que ele alterna as cores, ele deixa por exemplo inves de tres colunas azul, 1 azul, 1 vermelha, 1 amarela , 1 verde e 1 roxa.

Codigo:

private void createBarModels() {

```
    testeGrafico = initBarModel2();
    testeGrafico.setTitle("Bar Charts");
    testeGrafico.setAnimate(true);
    testeGrafico.setLegendPosition("ne");

    Axis yAxis = testeGrafico.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);

}

private BarChartModel initBarModel2() {
    BarChartModel model2 = new BarChartModel();

    graficoA = curvaABCDAO.listaClientes();

    graficoB = curvaABCDAO.listaClientesB();

    ChartSeries t1 = new ChartSeries();
    ChartSeries t2 = new ChartSeries();

    for (ChamadosEntity tc : graficoA) {
        t1.setLabel(tc.getAbc());
        t1.set(tc.getSolucao(), tc.getChamados());

    }

    for (ChamadosEntity tb : graficoB) {
        t2.setLabel(tb.getAbc());
        t2.set(tb.getSolucao(), tb.getChamados());

    }

    model2.addSeries(t1);
    model2.addSeries(t2);
    return model2;
}
```

Imagem do teste que fiz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca seu código onde você cria o gráfico,

Comment: essa sua imagem tá muito confusa. o BarChart do Primefaces trabalha com o conceito de série, e cada série(nesse caso) seria uma coluna de cada parte do gráfico. Nessa sua imagem, cada parte do gráfico é composta por toda a série.

Comment: Entendi, adicionei onde monto o gráfico,então não tem uma maneira de eu conseguir que as duas colunas do label A fiquem juntas?

Comment: acredito que não.

Comment: blz, vou dar mais uma pesquisa, vlw truta.